# A few questions concerning "universal colimits" and dense generating sets

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

My questions are triggered by
[Borceux](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YfzImoopB-IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=borceux+handbook+of+categorical+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LHVtU46ACsSU0AX1n4HABg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=borceux%20handbook%20of%20categorical%20algebra&f=false),
Vol 1, Proposition 4.5.6. The relevant part of the book is browsable
on [Google
Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YfzImoopB-IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=borceux+handbook+of+categorical+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LHVtU46ACsSU0AX1n4HABg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=borceux%20handbook%20of%20categorical%20algebra&f=false),
but i'll go ahead and reproduce at least the statement here anyway:

> Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a category with pullbacks and universal
>   coproducts (see section 2.14). Given a family $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ of
>   objects of $\mathfrak{C}$. the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (1) $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ is a regular family of generators
>
> (2) $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ is a dense family of generators

Since the definition of "universal coproducts" is not browsable in
google books, i'll attempt to paraphrase Borceux's definition: For a
category to have universal coproducts, whenever $\eta: E \rightarrow
\Delta Y$ are the coprojections of a coproduct, and $h: X \rightarrow
Y$ any arrow, then the pullback of $\eta$ along $\Delta h$ is another
set of coprojections for another coproduct. Here i use $\Delta$ to
denote the usual diagonal functor.

So my questions are as follows:

1. I do not think that the proof printed in Borceux is correct. Does
   anyone disagree with my criticisms, reproduced below?
2. I have produced what i think is a valid proof, but it is somewhat
   long winded (reproduced below). Does anyone have anything better?
3. Does anyone have any other references in the literature where this
   result (or a very similar one) is also stated and proved, for
   comparison's sake?
4. Is there an alternative, less overloaded, term for the concept of
   "universal coproducts" as defined in Borceux 2.14 and also (in an
   apparently weaker form) in
   [Jacobs](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Categorical_Logic_and_Type_Theory.html?id=0hhyL4WG3ngC&redir_esc=y),
   1.5.3. I vaguely remember seeing the same concept documented elsewhere
   under a different name, but i have forgotten where.

Here are my criticisms concerning Borceux's proof:

1. Minor misprint; I think $g \circ m$ should instead say $g_m$, where
   it appears.
2. At a later stage in the proof, Borceaux says that "... $(H_{f \circ
   u},(w_f)_f)$ and $(H_{f \circ v},(z_f)_f)$ are coproducts ...", but
   neither of these are of the right shape (i.e. they are not cocones)
   let alone (coprojections of a) coproduct, so i dispute this step
   altogether.
3. Let's take a simple case where $\mathfrak{C}$ is **Sets** and
   $\mathcal{G}$ is the family consisting of just one object - a two
   element set. Let $C$ also be a two element set. Then $\coprod_f G_i$
   is an eight element set. By restricting the kernel pair of $\gamma_C$,
   you may pick a minimal $X$ (with just 6 elements in it) and $u,v : X
   \rightarrow \coprod_f G_i$ such that $\gamma_C$ is a co-equaliser in
   such a way that $H_{f \circ u \circ v}$ is always empty. Thus the
   central result, that $g \circ u \circ x_f \circ z_f \circ l = g \circ
   v \circ x_f \circ z_f \circ l$ is vacuously true in this case, and
   goes no way to showing that $g \circ u = g \circ v$.
4. I also dispute the idea that we can deduce that $g \circ u = g
   \circ v$ by considering the cone property of $g_f$ in regards of only
   parallel pairs of arrows in $\mathcal{G}/C$, and the proof looks only
   at these scenarios. In the example produced in the previous criticism,
   the only non-trivial parallel pairs of arrows are not enough to fix
   $g_f$ in this way.

Here is my attempt at a correct proof. It took quite a bit of
headscratching to come up with. I eventually learned that you have to
use the universal coproducts quite aggresively to keep chopping up the
objects involved into manageable chunks until you can use familar
diagram chases to tease out a result. Because the proof is a bit more
complicated, I'm going to take the liberty of using a different (and
hopefully more familiar) set of symbols and notational style from that
in Borceux. The artefacts of the proof are represented on the
following diagram in $\mathbb{C}$:

$$ \begin{array}{cccccccc} \mathcal{G}(G) & \xrightarrow{g} &
\Gamma_r(s) & \xrightarrow{\hat{\rho}_s} & \Gamma_s(s) &
\xrightarrow{\hat{\sigma}{s}} & \mathcal{G}(S) \\ & & \downarrow
{\scriptstyle \rho_s} & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle \sigma_s} & &
\downarrow {\scriptstyle \eta_s} & \searrow {\scriptstyle s} \\ & &
\Gamma_s(t) & \xrightarrow{\tau_t} & P &
\overset{s'}{\underset{t'}{\rightrightarrows}} & Q &
\overset{\hat{\lambda}}{\longrightarrow} & C \\ & & &
\underset{=}{\searrow} & \uparrow {\scriptstyle \tau_t} & & \uparrow
{\scriptstyle \eta_t} & \nearrow {\scriptstyle t} \\ & & & &
\Gamma_t(t) & \xrightarrow{\hat{\tau}_t} & \mathcal{G}(T) \end{array}
$$

1. Let the regular generating family be represented as a full and
   faithful functor $\mathcal{G} : \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
   (we confuse the functor with its domain for economy)
2. Take arbitrary $C \in \text{Ob}(\mathbb{C})$ and let $\mathcal{G}
   \downarrow C$ be the usual comma category, with $\Gamma : (\mathcal{G}
   \downarrow C) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the canoncal projection and
   $\Gamma_0 : (\mathcal{G}_0 \downarrow C) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be
   the corresponding restriction to just objects. Objects of $\mathcal{G}
   \downarrow C$ will be confused with their underlying arrows $f :
   \mathcal{G}(G) \rightarrow C$ say, without danger of real confusion.
3. Take $Q$ the coproduct of $\Gamma_0$ and $\eta : \Gamma_0
   \rightarrow \Delta Q$ the coprojection. Let $\lambda : \Gamma
   \rightarrow \Delta C$ be the canoncal cocone with components
   $\lambda_f = f$ for all objects $f$ of $\mathcal{G} \downarrow C$.
   Let $\hat{\lambda} : Q \rightarrow C$ be the transpose along $\eta$ of (the
   restriction of) $\lambda$.
4. According to the hypothesis concerning $\mathcal{G}$ being a
   regular generating family, then $\hat{\lambda}$ is the co-equaliser of
   a pair of arrows $s', t' : P \rightarrow Q$ say.
5. Our aim is to show that $\lambda$ is the cocone of a colimit. To
   that end let $\mu : \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta D$ be any other cocone,
   and let $\hat{\mu} : Q \rightarrow D$ be the transpose along
   $\eta$. As long as we can show that this means that $\hat{\mu} \cdot
   s' = \hat{\mu} \cdot t'$, then a fairly simple appeal to the
   coequaliser and coproduct already mentioned shows that there is a
   unique $h : C \rightarrow D$ such that $\Delta h \cdot \lambda = \mu$
   and then the overall result follows immediately. The remainder of the
   proof focusses therefore only on showing that $\hat{\mu} \cdot s' =
   \hat{\mu} \cdot t'$.
6. Pullback $\eta$ along $\Delta s'$ to obtain $\Gamma_s$ and arrows
   $\sigma$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ (as seen in the above diagram). Similarly
   pullback $\eta$ along $\Delta t'$ to obtain $\Gamma_t$ and arrows
   $\tau$ and $\hat{\tau}$.
7. Choose any objects $s : \mathcal{G}(S) \rightarrow C$ and $t :
   \mathcal{G}(T) \rightarrow C$ of $\mathcal{G} \downarrow C$. Then let
   $\rho$ be the pullback of $\sigma$ along $\Delta \tau_t : \Delta
   \Gamma_s(t) \rightarrow \Delta P$ to obtain object $\Gamma_r$ and
   arrows $\rho$ and $\hat{\rho}$.
8. By the "universal coproduct" hypothesis, $\Gamma_r$, $\Gamma_t$,
   and $\Gamma_s$ are coproducts with coprojections $\rho$, $\tau$, and
   $\sigma$ respectfully.
9. Take suitable components to obtain the diagram above. The entire
   diagram commutes. Let $f$ be the entire composite from
   $\mathcal{G}(G)$ on the left to $C$ on the right. This gives three
   objects $f$, $s$, and $t$ and two arrows $\hat{\sigma}_s \cdot
   \hat{\rho}_s \cdot g$ and $\hat{\tau}_t \cdot \rho_s \cdot g$ in the
   category $\mathcal{G} \downarrow C$. Using the fact that $\mu$is a
   cocone, we thus learn that the above diagram commutes fully with
   $\mu_s$ in place of $s$, $\mu_t$ in place of $t$ and $\hat{\mu}$ in
   place of $\hat{\lambda}$.
10. This in turns tells us that $\hat{\mu} \cdot s' \cdot \tau_t \cdot
    \rho_s \cdot g = \hat{\mu} \cdot t' \cdot \tau_t \cdot \rho_s \cdot
    g$. Considering that $g$, $s$, and $t$ were all arbitrary,
    $\mathcal{G}$ is a generator set, and $\tau$ and $\rho$ are
    coprojections, we learn than $\hat{\mu} \cdot s' = \hat{\mu} \cdot
    t'$, and the proof is complete.

Comment: "Universal" is fairly standard and goes back to SGA 4. I suppose you could say "stable under pullback" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth a year later, I just made the same complaints as you and corrected the proof in the same way.